# Access jQuery to Elements after posting back via UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a small page with the following aspx markup

```
<fieldset style="width:40%; margin-left:50px;">
    <legend> Site User Role Management</legend>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSiteUserDDl" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlSiteUsers"
         Text="Manage the roles in which a user is registered by selecting the user from the dropdown list below."></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSiteUsers" runat="server" CssClass="dropdowns" AutoPostBack="True" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updplRoleChange"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset id="rolemanagement" style="width:80%;" Visible="false" runat="server" >
                    <legend id="rolemgmtlegend" runat="server"></legend>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentRole" runat="server"  CssClass="literaltext"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSiteUserRole" runat="server" CssClass="literaltext"></asp:Label><br /><br />
                                <asp:RadioButtonList id="rblstRoleChange" runat="server">
                                   <asp:ListItem selected="true">Add Role to User</asp:ListItem>
                                   <asp:ListItem>Remove Role from User</asp:ListItem>                                      
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserRoles" CssClass="dropdowns" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ClientIDMode="Static" /><br />
                                <asp:Button ID="submitrolechange" Text="Submit Role Change" CssClass="buttons"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Visible="False" />
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSiteUsers" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submitrolechange" EventName="Click"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
</fieldset>
```

and the following JQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlSiteUsers').change(function() {
            $(this).css({ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '1.1em', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        });
        //

        $('#updplRoleChange select').change(function () {
            $('#submitrolechange').show();
            $(this).css({ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '1.1em', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first function works, the second does not. There is no generated html for the markup within the update panel after using the first dropdown selector so Im not even sure if the selector id has actually stayed static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you change the second drop down list (as you set `AutoPostBack="True"`), color changes to Bold then posts back to server.

When returning from the server, it doesn't maintain the previous client state which is an expected behavior.

[image]

If you want to maintain the previous client state, you need to do something on page load like this.

```
<fieldset style="width: 40%; margin-left: 50px;">
    <legend>Site User Role Management</legend>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSiteUserDDl" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlSiteUsers"
        Text="Manage the roles in which a user is registered by selecting the user from the dropdown list below."></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSiteUsers" runat="server" CssClass="dropdowns" AutoPostBack="True" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="One" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="Two" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updplRoleChange" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset id="rolemanagement" runat="server">
                <legend id="rolemgmtlegend" runat="server"></legend>

                <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentRole" runat="server" CssClass="literaltext"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblSiteUserRole" runat="server" CssClass="literaltext"></asp:Label><br />
                <br />
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblstRoleChange" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="true">Add Role to User</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Remove Role from User</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserRoles" CssClass="dropdowns" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUserRoles_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="One" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="Two" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button ID="submitrolechange" Text="Submit Role Change" CssClass="buttons" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Visible="False" />
            </fieldset>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSiteUsers" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submitrolechange" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</fieldset>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlSiteUsers').change(function () {
            $(this).css({ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '1.1em', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        });
        //

        $('#updplRoleChange select').change(function () {
            $('#submitrolechange').show();
            $(this).css({ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '1.1em', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        });

    });

    function roleChange() {
        if ($('#updplRoleChange select').val() == "Two") {
            $('#updplRoleChange select').css({ 'color': 'black', 'font-size': '1.1em', 'font-weight': 'bold' });
        }
    }
</script>

protected void ddlUserRoles_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), UniqueID, "roleChange();", true);
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean here. The functions are wrapped in doc.ready. Are you referring to not page.IsPostback within the jquery function?how would one maintain the dropdown's css changes between postbacks in jquery?

Comment: You said `The first function works, the second does not.` My answer is both functions are working. You won't not see the result on second function, because the page is posted back to server as soon as it is called.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, I can see that in action,  but I'm not sure how to resolve that, How can I maintain the css state of that dropdown during that last postback?, that was the question.

Comment: I updated the answer. You want to render ScriptManager after ajax post back.

Comment: ty win, the answer is registering the script, which I was unfamiliar with but now am. In vb the code is ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), UniqueID, "roleChange();", True)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use live like so:

```
$('#updplRoleChange select').live("change", function(e) {
        // Do something exciting
});
```

Comment: I tried using live already, it makes the css change breifly, does not display the button and changes the css of the dropdown back to the original look